# Pandas conditionally fill a column using values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing costs for time periods:

| valid_from | valid_to | cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-10-09 23:00:00 | 2019-09-30 23:00:00 | 28.6700 |
| 2019-09-30 23:00:00 | 2021-03-18 00:00:00 | 26.2700 |
| 2022-10-13 23:00:00 | NaT | 39.7339 |

If 'valid_to' is NaT it means the cost is still current.

I want to add the correct cost to the time periods in the second dataframe which is broken into 30 minute periods:

| valid_from | valid_to | consumption | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-16 23:30:00 | 2023-09-17 00:00:00 | 0.040 | 39.7339 |
| 2023-09-17 00:00:00 | 2023-09-17 00:30:00 | 0.030 | 39.7339 |
| 2019-10-17 00:30:00 | 2019-10-17 01:00:00 | 0.030 | 26.2700 |
| 2018-10-16 20:30:00 | 2018-10-16 21:00:00 | 0.030 | 28.6700 |

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to get cost for rows where `valid_from` and `valid_to` overlap between the two dataframes - this is a form of inequality join which is effectively handled by [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# fill df1's valid_to with a timestamp in the future
df1.valid_to = df1.valid_to.fillna(pd.Timestamp.max)

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    ('valid_from', 'valid_from', '<='), 
    ('valid_to', 'valid_to', '>='), 
    df_columns='cost')
    #.move(source='cost',position='after',axis=1)
)
      cost          valid_from            valid_to  consumption
0  28.6700 2018-10-16 20:30:00 2018-10-16 21:00:00         0.03
1  26.2700 2019-10-17 00:30:00 2019-10-17 01:00:00         0.03
2  39.7339 2023-09-16 23:30:00 2023-09-17 00:00:00         0.04
3  39.7339 2023-09-17 00:00:00 2023-09-17 00:30:00         0.03
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is the fastest with 10k+ rows in the costs dataframe so I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Also kudos for readability.

Answer (score 1):

So since your ranges are datetime, you can create a `pd.IntervalIndex` for your first dataframe and use that to match with the date-ranges in the second dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
# fillna with a far-away date 
df1['valid_to'] = df1['valid_to'].fillna(pd.Timestamp('2200-12-30'))
df1.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['valid_from'],df1['valid_to'],closed='both')
```

I'm using apply with a lambda function (which has some checks), that will return cost from dataframe1 if a match exists

```
def lambda_func(r, colname='cost'):
    # get row number for "valid_from" and 'valid_to'
    try:
        row1 = df1.index.get_loc(r['valid_from'])
        row2 = df1.index.get_loc(r['valid_to'])
    except KeyError:
        return np.nan
    if row1 == row2:
        return df1.iloc[row1][colname]
    else:
        return np.nan

df2['cost'] = df2.apply(lambda r: lambda_func(r), axis=1)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
           valid_from            valid_to  consumption     cost
0 2023-09-16 23:30:00 2023-09-17 00:00:00         0.04  39.7339
1 2023-09-17 00:00:00 2023-09-17 00:30:00         0.03  39.7339
2 2019-10-17 00:30:00 2019-10-17 01:00:00         0.03  26.2700
3 2018-10-16 20:30:00 2018-10-16 21:00:00         0.03  28.6700
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works when the costs dataframe is in long intervals but doesn't work if it is in 30 min intervals like the consumption dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
bt_dates = (cost_df.values)  #a dataframe containing costs for time periods
'''
array([[Timestamp('2018-10-09 23:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2019-09-30 23:00:00'), 28.67],
       [Timestamp('2019-09-30 23:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2021-03-18 00:00:00'), 26.27],
       [Timestamp('2022-10-13 23:00:00'),
        Timestamp('2024-04-06 23:08:01.479568'), 39.7339]], dtype=object)
'''
```

Then, create a function:

```
def get_costs(row):
    for i in (bt_dates):
        if pd.notnull(i[1]):  # valid_to null or notnull?
            if (i[0] <= row["valid_from"]<= i[1]) & ((i[0] <= row["valid_to"]<= i[1])):
                return i[2]
                break
            else:
                pass
        else: # if valid_to is null, no need to check valid_to in main df
            if (i[0] <= row["valid_from"]):
                return i[2]
                break
            else:
                pass
```

Finally, apply function to main dataframe:

```
df["cost"] = df[["valid_from","valid_to"]].apply(get_costs, axis=1)
```

**Test**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'valid_from': [Timestamp('2023-09-16 23:30:00'), Timestamp('2023-09-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-10-17 00:30:00'), Timestamp('2018-10-16 20:30:00')], 'valid_to': [Timestamp('2023-09-17 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2023-09-17 00:30:00'), Timestamp('2019-10-17 01:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-10-16 21:00:00')]})
df
'''
           valid_from            valid_to
0 2023-09-16 23:30:00 2023-09-17 00:00:00
1 2023-09-17 00:00:00 2023-09-17 00:30:00
2 2019-10-17 00:30:00 2019-10-17 01:00:00
3 2018-10-16 20:30:00 2018-10-16 21:00:00

'''
df["cost"] = df[["valid_from","valid_to"]].apply(get_costs, axis=1)
```

**Out**:

```
           valid_from            valid_to     cost
0 2023-09-16 23:30:00 2023-09-17 00:00:00  39.7339
1 2023-09-17 00:00:00 2023-09-17 00:30:00  39.7339
2 2019-10-17 00:30:00 2019-10-17 01:00:00  26.2700
3 2018-10-16 20:30:00 2018-10-16 21:00:00  28.6700
```